# IOS dispatch_async view will disappear

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

I am using dispatch_async and a block to retrieve server data every 3 seconds or so. What is the method of handling the view either disappearing or the user shutting the program down?

Would it be a boolean flag that the async block checks every now and then? If so, what if the view exits while the async block is sleeping?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot easily cancel a dispatch call, so your best bet is to move to an `NSOperation` instead. There is a highly relevent video from WWDC 2012, [Session 211 - Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=211) which covers precisely the kind of problem you describe. I definitely suggest you watch it.

The basic approach is to create an `NSBlockOperation` which can check the `-isCancelled` property on itself to return early if it gets cancelled. Then you can cancel the operation in `viewDidDisappear`.

An alternative approach would be to use `NSTimer` which can also be easily invalidated/cancelled. This might actually be the simplest solution for you given the description of what your code is doing.

Comment: +1 for the reference to WWDC 2012 Session 211.  An excellent video.